# Validators what is the best way?

Tags: java, zk

Using validators like this:

```
public class FormFieldValidator {

   [...]

   public Validator getCallsignValidator() {
        return new Validator() {

            [...]

        };
    }

   [...]

}
```

Does this mean that  always that ZK invokes the validator a new validator instance is created , so for example when we are testing our validators they stay on memory , or worse , they stay referenciated by ZK?

So my question is:

Is there a better way ?

Comment: You will probably get more responses if you accept a few answers for your previous questions.

Comment: that answer sure was productive

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this code snippet every time a new validator object would be created and would stay in memory as long as the reference to this validator exists anywhere.